# VueJS FileReader

Tags: vue.js, filereader, exceljs, sheetjs

I'm trying to use ExcelJS in Vue and I need FileReader to read and parse the files but I'm getting errors. How do I use FileReader with VueJS?

**Input Form**

```html
    <input type="file" 
        id="importProductionSchedule" 
        name="importProductionSchedule" 
        @change="checkFile($event)" 
        ref="importProductionSchedule"
    >
```

**checkFile method**

```js
    checkFile() {
        let reader = new FileReader()
        let self = this

        reader.onload = (e) => {
            let bstr = e.target.result
            let wb = XLSX.read(bstr, {type:'binary'})
            let wsname = wb.SheetNames[0]
            let ws = wb.Sheets[wsname]
            let data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws, {header:1})
            self.form.filedata = data
            self.cols = make_cols(ws['!ref'])
        }
        reader.onerror = (stuff) => {
            console.log("error", stuff)
            console.log (stuff.getMessage())
        }
        // reader.readAsArrayBuffer(event)
        reader.readAsBinaryString(event.target.files[0])
    },
```

First of all, logging event.target.files[0] in the console would return the file, but I'm testing both event and event.target.files[0] to make sure.

These are my errors:

```js
    event = Uncaught Error: cannot read as File: {"isTrusted":true}
    event.target.files[0] = Uncaught Error: cannot read as File: {}
```

Comment: I think you just need to receive the event here `checkFile(event) {...`

Comment: @RichardMatsen regardless if I add the event or argument or not, the event  variable is passed. I tested both ways and both log results of the same event data

Comment: I'm not sure how the event gets in if you don't have a parameter. I guess if you put a console.log before the `reader.readAsBinaryString(` line, you get correct info about your file?

Comment: I tried this code: reader.readAsArrayBuffer(event.target.files), then the error returns: Uncaught Error: cannot read as File: {"0":{}}

It seems like object inside the target.files is empty event though it has a file attached onto it already

Comment: Sorry, I got lost when you told me the event was getting picked up even though it's not passed in. Normally in Vue events are handled with `v-on:` syntax, not `@` syntax.

Comment: Here's one that works [CodePen](https://codepen.io/Atinux/pen/qOvawK/).

Comment: instead of  `e.target.files` use `e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files`

Comment: I'm getting undefined in dataTransfer. 
I realized it must have something to do with this that I setup in webpack because I cannot run Filereader properly:
node: {
    fs: "empty",
  },

Comment: I think I made a mistake. I'm trying to use these packages:

// var fs = require('fs')
// var FileReader = require('FileReader')

is this filereader the same as the html5 used in the demo? @RichardMatsen

Answer (score 2):

you can use below method

```js
createImage(file) {
    let reader = new FileReader()
    reader.onload = (event) => {
        this.product.image = event.target.result
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file)
}
```

Comment: This seem to only work for me on images.  what about not image files?  I've tried readAsBinaryString, readAsArrayBuffer and readAsText none of them seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
    methods:{
        uploadImage(event) {
        const image = event.target.files[0];
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(image);
        reader.onload = (event) => {
        this.previewImage = event.target.result;
       };
     }, 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input class="patientPorting"
type="file"
@change="onFilePicked( $event )"/>
```

Create below method to get the file.

```
const onFilePicked = (event) =>{

        const fData = event.target.files[0];
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(fData);
        reader.onload = (event) => {
            fileData = event.target.result;
        };
        console.log(fileData);
        jsonObj = [];
        jsonObj.push({
            "fileData" : fileData,
            "fileName":fData.name,
            "fileSize":fData.size,
            "fileType":fData.type,
        }
       );
    }
```